# Parsing number from string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-parsing

How do I split selected value, seperate the number from text in jQuery?

Example:

`myselect` contains `c4`

Just get only the number `4`.

```
$('select#myselect').selectToUISlider({
      sliderOptions: {
        stop: function(e,ui) {
          var currentValue = $('#myselect').val();
          alert(currentValue);
          var val = currentValue.split('--)
          alert(val);

        }
      }
    });
```

Comment: Please use a meaningful, relevant title.

Comment: There's a syntax error in the line above the last alert. Your second hyphen should be the ending single quote mark. With that said, is the value actually "c-4" rather than "c4" as you had said? If not, why are you splitting on '-'?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use regex to pull only the numbers.

```
var value = "c4";
alert ( value.match(/\d+/g) );
```

edit: changed regex to `/\d+/g` to match numbers greater than one digit (thanks @Joseph!)

Comment: that'll work. Only thing I'd add to that is use the + wildcard after \d to include greater than 1 digit numbers

Comment: @JosephMarikle "greater than **or equal to** 1 digit numbers"

Answer (score 4):

1) if it's always : 1 letter that followed by numbers you can do simple substring:

```
'c4'.substring(1); // 4 
'c45'.substring(1); // 45
```

2) you can also replace all non-numeric characters with regular expression:

```
'c45'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // 45
'abc123'.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); // 123
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the prefix is always only one character long you could use this:

```
var val = currentValue.substr(1);
```